# Null values for strings are being counted in GBQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a survey table where the answers are string type and of course, not every respondent answered each question. Now my issue is that I've assigned the empty rows to null and when counting distinct values the nulls get counted as well. I am using Plotly for the visualization and I am certain the issue doesn't lie there. When using SELECT DISTINCT in BigQuery on a column the nulls still show up and are also displayed on the graph. The schema also has these columns as nullable

[image]

I have tried assigning an empty string to the empty rows which didn't make sense to me and as expected resulted in the empty rows being counted as well. I am not sure how to proceed from here if anyone has any advice on where the issue might lie it would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Hi @Solrac, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches.

Comment: Hi @PrajnaRaiT sorry for the lack of response. Your answer didn't solve the issue it lay with an error within one of the built-in Plotly functions.

Comment: Can you provide the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I have created some dummy data to try to replicate your issue, when I run the following:

```sql
WITH data AS(
  SELECT "Yes" AS column UNION ALL
  SELECT "No" AS column UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS column
)
SELECT COUNT(column) AS count FROM data
```

I get the result `2`, which is expected, ignoring the `NULL` value.

I see in your screenshot above you are selecting `DISTINCT` values, which will return three distinct values, with `NULL` being one of them, as you can see below:

```sql
WITH data AS(
  SELECT "Yes" AS column UNION ALL
  SELECT "No" AS column UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS column
)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM data
```

If you want to see a count of two distinct values then you should use the `COUNNT()` function, rather than selecting with `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

To return the rows which doesn’t contain null values, you can use the below query:

```
WITH table AS(
 SELECT "Yes" AS value UNION ALL
 SELECT "No" AS value UNION ALL
 SELECT NULL AS value
)
Select *
from table
where value is not NULL;
```

**Output:**

[image]

And to count the number of rows which doesn’t contain the null values, you can consider the below query:

```
Select countif(value != 'null') count from table
```

**Output:**

[image]